# pass json_encode array to java through network

Tags: java, php, arrays, networking, serialization

I am working on a coursework where I am trying to pass an array from php 'client' to java 'server'. I create an array in php, encode it with json_encode and receive it on the server site with StringVariable.readLine(). 
My problem:

The values of the php array are received as one value of the array in java. Have a look on the code and the output please.

**PHP - as 'sender'**

```
$array = array("foo", "bar", "hallo", "world");
$array2 = json_encode($array);
//var_dump($array);

$socket = fsockopen($server, $port, $eN, $eS);  

if ($socket)  
{  

fwrite($socket, $array2);
```

**Java - as 'receiver'**

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket1.getInputStream())); 

 while ((in1 = in.readLine()) != null) 
                {  
                    String[] Decoder = {in1};
                    System.out.println(Arrays.asList(Decoder));
```

**Results**

[["foo","bar","hallo","world"]]

I ama generally looking for a solution where I pass array from PHP to JAVA through my lan. Any solution would be great.. I have tried also **serialize()** and what I receive is

[a:4:{i:0;s:3:"foo";i:1;s:3:"bar";i:2;s:5:"hallo";i:3;s:5:"world";}]

Help will be much apprecieted!!! THANK YOU!

Comment: Hint: add a JSON decoder on the receiving side. So far, you're treating it like a string. Not sure why you're wrapping it in a one-element array, though.

Comment: The simpler way: implode() on php side, String.split() on Java side. That is, only if you know a character that can be used as a separator reliably!

Answer (score 0):

You would use `json_encode` in PHP just like you are, and then a JSON decoder on the Java side; there's several (Jackson and Gson are both popular ones).

Here's a basic example using [Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/):

```
String[] myStrings = new Gson().fromJson(in1, String[].class);
```

Better yet is not to use an array in Java, but a List:

```
Type type = new TypeToken<List<String>>(){}.getType();
List<String> myStrings = new Gson().fromJson(in1, type);
```